# ViewpagerIndicator hides the tabs content in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Am using 'ViewPagerIndicator' library for getting tabs in middle of the layout. Am placing the 'TabPageIndicator' and 'ViewPager' in 'ScrollView'.

Here My problem is tabs are visible but content Views are invisible.I found this using 'HierarchyViewer'.

My layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white_color"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <ViewAnimator
        android:id="@+id/view__root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
              style="@style/LinearLayout.Vertical">                  

            <RelativeLayout
                .....>    
                <ImageView
                    ..... />    
                <TextView
                    .... />
            </RelativeLayout>                 

            <LinearLayout
                ......>
                <TextView
                    ...../>                
            </LinearLayout>          

            <LinearLayout
               .....>
                <TextView
                    ..../>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                ........>

                <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                    ......../>
            </LinearLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
                .......>

                <ImageView
                    ...../>
                <ImageView
                    ...... />
                <ImageView
                    ....../>
                <ImageView
                    ..../>

               </RelativeLayout>   

            <LinearLayout
                ......>

                <ListView
                    ......./>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_viewpageindicator"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">  

            <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator_1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/> 

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_1"               
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

       </LinearLayout>            

    </LinearLayout> 

    </ViewAnimator>
</ScrollView>
```

Please any one help me.
 Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `android:fillViewport="true"` to your ScrollView and set its `layout_height` to `"fill_parent"`.